# A more elegant way to handle notices/warnings

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, errors, warnings, notices

I have a wordpress site with a number of different plugins (about 75) all created by me, old and new included. With the evolution of WP and PHP/MySQL, some of the functions in the plugins have deprecated and hence generate warnings and notices and a lot of them.

What I am planning to do is edit each of them individually to fix the warnings/notices. It would take me a lot of time and I can not be sure if I would have covered all the code as it is large. Hence, I would like to know if there is a more elegant way of overriding and catching all warnings/notices and handling them at one place. This would make my life a lot easier, as many of the warnings are repetitive.

Thanks.

Comment: You can always change the [error reporting level](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), but of course the best course long term is to fix those errors/notices. They might not take as long as you're expecting...

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice (and suitable for production) to log the errors, instead (or in addition to) displaying them. See [Configure Error Logging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Error_Logging) in Codex.

I usually combine it with my [Error Log Dashboard Widget](https://github.com/Rarst/error-log-dashboard-widget) plugin for bit of UI on live servers.